# execve() argv in GAS AT&T assembler

Tags: assembly, x86-64, system-calls, shellcode, execve

**My code:**

```
.section .data
name: .string "/bin/sh"
args:
        .string "-c"
        .string "ls"

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
        pushq $0
        pushq name

        movq $59, %rax
        movq %rsp, %rdi

        pushq $0
        pushq args

        movq %rsp, %rsi
        movq $0, %rdx

        syscall
```

I know that the second argument of `execve` is array of chars.

How to do this in assembly avoiding this:

```
execve("./payload", ["./payload"], 0x7ffc291fd160 /* 40 vars */) = 0
execve("/bin/sh", [0x736c00632d], NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xfffffffffffffff2} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: The second argument to `execve` is a pointer to an array of pointers to characters, i.e. an array of strings, not an array of chars.  That's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: If I change .asciz to .string the same output

Comment: Is this ultimately for a buffer exploit?

Comment: It's for my first shellcode, I am a CTF student.

Comment: @EntyAV That doesn't change anything; `.asciz` is an alias to `.string`.  You need an array of strings, not an array of characters.  That is, an array of pointers to arrays of characters.  The last pointer must be `NULL` and the last character in each array of characters must be a NUL character (`.asciz` ensures that for you).

Comment: @fuz I can't understand. Maybe you can fix this code as you described?

Answer (score 2):

The `execve` system call has signature

```
execve(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

The argument vector is an array of strings, that is, a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of characters.  You however supplied a pointer to an array of characters, which is incorrect and will not work.  To fix this, add an array of pointers referring to your arguments:

```
        .section .data
name:   .string "/bin/sh"
arg1:   .string "-c"
arg2:   .string "ls"

args:   .quad name
        .quad arg1
        .quad arg2
        .quad 0

        .section .text
        .globl _start
_start: movq $59, %rax
        leaq name(%rip), %rdi
        leaq args(%rip), %rsi
        movq $0, %rdx

        syscall
```

See how now `args` is a NULL-terminated array of pointers to the arguments.  Also note that the first argument (at index 0) is conventionally the program name itself.  It won't work as expected to pass an actual option there.

I have also simplified the code by loading the addresses of the strings directly using a `lea` instruction instead of the roundabout way you used.

Comment: This is eventually going to be shellcode so there was a reason they was trying to build the arguments on the stack.  I believe an answer that would be more preferable here would be one that builds the the arguments on the stack and passes addresses to the stack data to the `syscall`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch My answer aims to explain the required data structure.  It's still OPs problem to make this work as shell code.

Comment: @fuz how to make it work as shellcode, I am new and can't understand why generated shellcode calls Illigal instruction error. Maybe I should write payloads in NASM, not GAS.

Comment: @EntyAV The choice of assembler doesn't really matter.  There are multiple ways to make this work in shell code.  As a beginner, it's a bit difficult and not really a task I recommend doing.  The general idea is to build the arrays on the stack instead of having them in the data section.